# Placing children of a component into a different component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a component which takes the children provided to it and displays them in a different component.

For example, let's say I have the following layout:

```
<Layout>
    <PageContent />
    <Sidebar />
</Layout>
```

...and within the `PageContent`, I want to use another component (e.g. `<SidebarContent>`), such that the children given to the `SidebarContent` component are rendered as children of the `Sidebar`.

**Example PageContent**:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const PageContent = () => (
    <>
        <p>Page Content</p>
        <SidebarContent>Sidebar Content</SidebarContent>
    </>
  )
}

export default PageContent
```

What is considered best practice for achieving this?

Comment: *Maybe* portals? https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: I've not come across portals before! I'll have a read. Thanks

Comment: you can use either redux(or any global state manager) to manage the data flow or define the data in the parent (for this example Layout is the parent) and pass the data through parent to children

Comment: @Ehsan might this also be a good case for the context API?

Comment: @markmoxx 
you can use context API but you have to wrap your main component (Layout for this example) to access other components children. like redux which uses Provider at the top level.